# Projective space minus point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

It is not difficult to see that $\mathbb{A}^n-\{\text{point}\}$ is not an affine variety for $n \geq 2$. Is the same true for $\mathbb{P}^n-\{\text{point}\}$? I think it is not difficult to show it is not projective variety but I am not sure if it is affine variety or not. I tried to compute the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^n-\{\text{point}\}$ but did not find what it is.

Comment: It contains complete curves, hence cannot be affine.

Comment: @Sasha can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a curve in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ not containing $\{pt\}$ and consider $X\subset\mathbb{P}_k^n-\{pt\}$. Then $X$ is projective over $k$. If $\mathbb{P}_k^n-\{pt\}$ were affine over $k$, $X$ would be affine over $k$. Now, a curve can't be both projective and affine because its dimension is $1$ (see e.g. [Which affine schemes are projective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855943/which-affine-schemes-are-projective)).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why dimension 1 implies it cannot be both projective and affine? I haven't learned anything about scheme

Comment: Hartshorne I.3.4a: the global regular functions on a projective variety are the constant functions. An affine variety has global regular functions given by its coordinate ring, i.e. a quotient of a polynomial ring by an ideal. The two coincide when the defining ideal is maximal, meaning the variety in question is a finite set of points.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you